# Overriding and overloading in Java. What does changing the visibility do?

Tags: java

I would like to know if this is correct and some explanation for each question:

i. `public int compute(double x)`

ii. `public void compute(double x)`

iii. `public void compute(int x)`

iv. `public void compute()`

v. `private void compute()`

1. Does method i. overload method ii.? Yes/No... NO, would cause an error
2. Does method i. overload method iii.? Yes/No ...NO, would cause error
3. Does method i. overload method iv.? Yes/No ...NO
4. Does method iv. overload method v.? Yes/No ...NO, would cause error?
5. Does method ii. overload method iii.? Yes/No ...YES

Comment: Your answers are a bit off.  Please read [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) and come back here if you still can't figure out the answers.

Comment: methods with the same name but different signature are considered as overlodes

Comment: @ASdi "Signature" being defined as number, type, and order of parameters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Indeed , so am I wrong ?

Comment: No, you're right but this is a poorly-worded homework dump.  I'm not answering it.

Comment: Considered trying it?

Comment: if you want to know if it is a valid overload just try to compile it and you'll know based on if it throws a compiler error. Honestly, its ridiculous to be asking if some code will throw a compiler error!

Answer (score 0):

A method's visibility is not part of its signature. You cannot overload a method with another method with different visibility. When extending a class, you can make a method **more** visible when overriding it (e.g., promote a `protected` method to `public`).

Return types also aren't part of the signature, and you can't overload a method with the another method that has a different return type. You can, however, *specialize* a return value when you extend a class. E.g., if the base class has a method `public Object getSomething()`, you can specialize the return value in an extending class - e.g., `public String getSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

If these methods are all in the same class, then you are overloading.
When overloading, you can have functions with the same name, but they must have different arguments.

```
//an example of over-loading
public void foo(){...}
public void foo(String str){...};
```

But having different return types for methods with the same name doesn't qualify as overloading.

```
//an example of what is NOT overloading and will not compile
public void foo(){...}
public String foo(){...}
```

The compiler can't tell which method to invoke!